# Sails js - waterline orm - mysql. Tables autogeneration

Tags: mysql, orm, sails.js, waterline

When I create my model in sails - waterline the db is autogenerated.
The problem is that my primary keys are unsigned int(10) and the external keys are int(11) (with sign). In fact the relationship is only in my models and not in db.
A code example is the following:

```
// A user may only have a single pet
var User = Waterline.Collection.extend({

identity: 'user',
connection: 'local-postgresql',

attributes: {
  firstName: 'string',
  lastName: 'string',

// Add a reference to Pet
  pet: {
    model: 'pet'
  }
 }
});

var Pet = Waterline.Collection.extend({

 identity: 'pet',
 connection: 'local-postgresql',

 attributes: {
  breed: 'string',
  type: 'string',
  name: 'string',

   // Add a reference to User
   user: {
     model: 'user'
   }
 }
});
```

In this example my database is generated in the following way:
pet "id" (in pet table) is an autoincrement primary key unsigned int(10)
and "pet" (in user table that is an external key pointing to pet id) is a int(11) (signed int). There is a solution to that problem? thanks

Comment: Do you want to stop auto generation?

Comment: No, I would like to have a correct generation! Is it possibile? What happens if I leave the primary key unsigned int and foreign key signed int? Might I have unexpected result?

Answer (score 0):

The `sails-postgresql` adapter does not yet create foreign key relationships in the database itself. This is not *incorrect* and doesn't affect how you use sails/waterline. Everything will work fine, this is just an optimization that hasn't been implemented yet.

There's an open issue if you'd like to share your thoughts there: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-postgresql/issues/123

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the problem is that the primary key is an unsigned int and the foreign key is a signed int!!! In fact if I want to create manually the relation, it is not possible! Now, the answer is, if I make a join between these different field type is a problem?
PS: my db is mysql and not postegresql (but I think that the behavior is the same)